# JAWS 16 screen-reader is not reading custom control type in win32 application

Tags: winapi, custom-controls, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have two buttons (one is standard button caption"OK" and another is custom control button caption "Submit") in my win32 application. JAWS screen-reader is speaking out correctly the standard button "OK Button, To activate press space bar" but for custom button it is speaking only "Submit" not speaking "Submit button, to activate press space bar".

Can you tell me a way by providing any samples or documents to support this accessibility issue in win32 application. I am new here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about UI automation

Comment: After you do read that, I will say (as a precaution) that I have a feeling that JAWS is reading the supplementary text based on the button's control type/role, not the button's name.

Comment: http://www.codemag.com/article/0810112

Comment: UI Automation and above link helped me a lot to learn.